# Swift textview (scrollview) & pangesturerecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I've searched for 2 days about this. There are already a lot of questions like this but no question or answer is exactly what I need. So I hope you can help me out.

So I've a chatbar. It's first flat and you can type in it. If you have a long text and have multiple lines, the flat chatbar will expand. But only for max 5 lines, after the 5th line, you can still type but it will not show all the text, you need to scroll to see it. But for sending the message you need to swipe it up. So I've added a pangesture to the textview. But now you can't scroll anymore. What I need is something that looks if it needs to use the pangesture or the scroll.

This is when you have multiple lines: (there are more lines, some are not visible so that's why user needs to scroll)

[image]

This is when the message is swiped up, all lines are visible (this isn't important but I just show this so maybe you understand my app more)

[image]

I hope someone can help me. I've tried 1000 methods but no one works how I want it to work.

Comment: did you add send button at the end of textview ?

Comment: no there is no send button, you need to swipe the message , this has nothing to do with my problem. I just want something that checks if it needs to scroll or slide

Comment: Is it really required to use pan gesture to send message? As I though you can implement pull to refresh type of system to send message. i.e. user will scroll to bottom and for send he just pull the textview in upper direction you can show send animation just like pull to refresh pull to send feature.

Comment: @TheiOSDev The blue line around it must move too. So I don't know if that's possible with the method you just said?

Comment: https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController , Check link , In it they used growing textview for some lines after that just text moves up.User can see text with scrolling any time.

Comment: If I don't add the pangesture, I can scroll , if I add it I can not scroll but only move it up. What I need is something that check's if the textview is at the bottom then it needs to use pangesture otherwise scroll

Comment: Are you currently not able to move line with scroll view delegate methods?

Comment: You are in trouble of chat view scrollview, text view scroll view and pan gesture, all of them receipt  vertical swipe. The solution for this is you add delegate for text view scrollview, see when it  scroll and figure out velocity of scroll, if it large than some value -> send message